# How do I delete a Facebook app from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

What is the process to permanently remove an app from Facebook using the Facebook Developer App Dashboard?

I have found only one answer and I don't know if it works: to put it on *Sandbox Mode* and wait for Facebook to delete it. That doesn't seem right. Apparently it is so easy for someone who has no experience to spam Facebook with empty apps and no visible way to delete them.

Know that I did try to do this myself and couldn't find something like a "Delete this app permanently" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to the [app dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)
2. Select the app you want to delete from the list of your apps
3. Click 'Edit Settings' in the middle of the main part of the page
4. Click 'Delete App' on the left hand column
5. Click 'Confirm' when the message pops up asking you to confirm

[image: Screenshot of the Delete app link]

Comment: This is why I made this question, I don't see a delete app button.

Comment: Are you sure you're an admin of the app? if you can't change the app secret in the app settings you're probably only a 'developer', not an 'administrator'